# Connecting python script to microcontroller

Tags: python, serial-port

I am trying to send textual commands to a microcontroller through usb serial port (ttyUSB0), the controller should respond with 'Y' or 'N' and execute the command. Commands are given in the following form '@01a' where the @ is beginning symbol 0 is position for A channel and 1 position for B channel and 'a' is checksum of A+B.

I'm stuck and a beginner in python so any help is welcome and appreciated.

p.s. when I connect using putty everything works as expected 
also the OS is Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

This is my code:

```
import time
import serial
import binascii

ser = serial.Serial(
port='/dev/ttyUSB0',
baudrate=19200,

)

print 'Enter your commands below.\r\nInsert "exit" to leave the application.'


AT =  chr(int('1000000',2))
A =  chr(int('100000',2))
B =  chr(int('100000',2))
AB =  chr(int('1000000',2))

input = AT + A + B + AB

print input

try: 
  ser.open()
except Exception, e:
 print "error open serial port: " + str(e)
 exit()

if ser.isOpen():

  try:
    ser.flushInput() #flush input buffer, discarding all its contents
    ser.flushOutput()#flush output buffer, aborting current output 
             #and discard all that is in buffer

    #write data
    ser.write(input)
   # print("write data: AT+CSQ")

    time.sleep(0.5)  #give the serial port sometime to receive the data

    numOfLines = 0

    while True:
      response = ser.readline()
      print("read data: " + response)

    numOfLines = numOfLines + 1

    if (numOfLines >= 5):


     ser.close()
except Exception, e1:
    print "error communicating...: " + str(e1)

else:
  print "cannot open serial port "
```

Comment: Can you post an error or what is going wrong with your code?

Comment: @kosnik nothing is wrong with the code, it compiles but the controller is not responding

Comment: I have used this code and connected successfully.

now I just need to send the 4 characters...

import serial
import time

ser = serial.Serial()
ser.braudrate = 19200
ser.port = "/dev/ttyUSB0"
ser.open()

print(ser.name)
if ser.isOpen():
    print("serial is open!")

ser.close()

Comment: As an idiot check, connect TX to RX, to see exactly what you are sending. then once that is good, connect back to your device.

Comment: @Reroute It is saying that port is already open, although nothing is using the port